# Bad bind variable in audit trail trigger in Oracle 11g R2

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2

I have been trying to construct audit trail triggers and procedures in oracle and I am facing a problem with bind variables. Following is the code

```
create or replace trigger trg_audit_trail
for insert or update or delete 
on tbl_mst_books
referencing NEW AS New OLD AS Old
for each row
declare
  colName VARCHAR2(50);
  cursor audit_cur is
   select column_name from all_tab_columns where table_name = 'tbl_mst_books';
begin
  for rec_audit in audit_cur loop
   colName := rec_audit.column_name;
   if inserting then
    if (inserting(colName)) then
     prc_audit_trail('tbl_mst_books',colName,:new.colName);    /*stored procedure call
              to insert audit trail data from multiple triggers to audit trail table */
    end if;
   end if;
 end loop;
end trg_audit_trail;
```

The stored procedure `prc_audit_trail` is now inserting the values passed as parameters into audit trail tables.
The problem I am having is with the bind variable `:new`. I am getting an error of `bad bind variable`. Apparently I am not being able to do `:new.colName` but instead of `colName` if I directly write the name of the column(eg: `BOOK_NAME` or `BOOK_AUTHOR`) it's not giving any error. Since I have to fetch the column name of the affected column I am fetching the column name to a variable and trying to do `:new.colName`. How can I resolve the issue?? Please help me. Also can I get column names of the affected columns(during insert, update and delete) in some other way?
Why am i getting the bad bind variable error for `:new.colName`? How can I resolve it??

P.S. I have just shown the portion for `IF INSERTING` but I am following the same process for `IF UPDATING` in the same trigger where I am getting the same error also for `:old.colName`

Thank you.

Comment: 1. I presume that should be `before insert or ...` 2. Remove the redundant line `referencing ...`, it's not needed. 3. I can't find any documentation for `inserting(<column_name>)`; I'm pretty sure that only works for `updating(<column_name>)`.

Comment: Actually the trigger will fire 'after insert'. I have removed 'referencing' as you have advised but I am stuck with the error.

Answer (score 1):

If you write `:new.colName` than you are referencing the new value of a column named "COLNAME" of table tbl_mst_books. But table tbl_mst_books has no column named "COLNAME". Actually there is no possibility to do this this way because dynamic sql does not work with :new and :old bind values. You have to program it explicitly for every column in your table and have to change your code if your table structure changes.

see [AskTom](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0%3a%3a%3a%3aP11_QUESTION_ID:734825535375)

Answer (score -1):

Try removing the ':' because new is not a bind variable.

Comment: Removing ':' is not working either. I guess it will not work if I assign column name dynamcicall to a variable and use it like that. Is there any other way to insert column names dynamically as the business demands it.